# Bind9 DNS Server configuration

Tags: networking, ubuntu, debian, dns

I'm having trouble with Bind9 setup.

named.conf.local :

```
zone "techvision.me" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/db.techvision.me";
    };
zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/db.192.168.1";
    };
```

named.conf.options :

```
    dnssec-validation auto;

    // Listen on local interfaces
    listen-on-v6 { none; };
    listen-on { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.1.0/24; any; };


    forwarders { 192.168.1.1; 1.1.1.1; };

    allow-query { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.1.0/24; any; };

    version none;
    recursion yes;
    allow-recursion { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.1.0/24; any; };
};
```

db.techvision.me :

```
$TTL 3600
@       IN      SOA     hostmaster.techvision.me. gal.techvision.me. (
                    20
                    3600
                    600
                    1209600
                    3600 )
;
;       Name server
;
@       IN      NS      hostmaster.techvision.me.
hostmaster        IN      A       192.168.1.254
;
;       Host addresses
;
hostmaster       IN      A       192.168.1.254
router           IN      A       192.168.1.1
nas              IN      A       192.168.1.100
vmware           IN      A       192.168.1.150
```

db.192.168.1 :

```
$TTL 3600
@       IN      SOA     hostmaster.techvision.me. gal.techvision.me. (
                        21
                        3600
                        600
                        1209600
                        3600 )
;
;       Name server
;
@       IN      NS      hostmaster.techvision.me.
hostmaster      IN      A       192.168.1.254
;
;       Addresses point to canonical name
;
1       IN      PTR     router.techvision.me.
254     IN      PTR     hostmaster.techvision.me.
100     IN      PTR     nas.techvision.me.
150     IN      PTR     vmware.techvision.me.
```

and my windows host is configured as followed :

[image: Windows Host Screenshot]

(only 1 dns server to the bind9 server)

**The thing is that if I check from the bind9 server i've got a respond.
but with the windows host i'm not getting a respond for those hosts.
Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Have you checked if you have a firewall that is blocking traffic with a destination port of 53?

Comment: ufw not installed.
ss -tulpn output that all working good.
after a bit of digging maybe it has something to do with the bind files permissions.
I think i'll remove the machine and start a new one, maybe I ruined something in the proccess.
Any other suggestions ?

Comment: *"With the Windows Host, I'm not getting a response for those hosts."* - It might be worth [edit]ing the question to include details of the exact steps your are using in testing. Also, clarifying if this DNS server is operating under WSL2 could be helpful (considering you have used the term "Windows Host" twice).

Comment: what does "iptables -vnL" say?

Comment: iptables -vnL output that everything is empty 
if it helps,
I just ssh to the nas client,
everything seems to work correctly there.
for some reason only the window host can't "Join" or what ever.

Answer (score 1):

> Any other suggestions?

A couple thoughts:

- You may want to consider replacing `192.168.1.1` in your `forwarders` statement with something else e.g. `8.8.8.8` (Google DNS:

  ```
  forwarders { 8.8.8.8; 1.1.1.1; };
  ```

  Assuming `192.168.1.1` is e.g. your router (as indicated) and not another DNS server, there likely isn't a reason to list it in `forwarders`.
- Your `listen-on` statement seems possibly redundant. `listen-on { any; };` should cover all interfaces and IP addresses.
- You may consider simply using `localnets` (in combination with `localhost` if you like) for `allow-query` and `allow-recursion`:

  ```
   allow-query { localhost; localnets; };

   version none;
   recursion yes;
   allow-recursion { localhost; localnets; };
  ```

  If you run into issues, you can still potentially use `{ 127.0.0.1; 192.168.1.0/24; };` from your original example. However, [using `any` is not recommended](https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-00269) because:

> clients spoofing queries can use your servers to launch distributed denial-of-service attacks.

- Don't forget to increment your serial number in your zone records if you make changes to them (the first line with `20` and `21` in your examples). BIND will need a reload/restart as well.

**Windows Host**

I don't know your network or intent, but assuming you want this DNS server to be used for all the devices on your network, the individual "Windows Host" DNS settings may not be the way to go.

Instead, you may want to consider using the default "Obtain DNS server address automatically" in Windows and simply set this DNS server up as the one to use on your router (ex. use the DNS server's local `192.x.x.x` IP in place of your ISP's DNS servers).

---

*If you wish to access `techvision.me` from outside your local network, you router will likely need to forward port 53 (and to be safe, perhaps port 953) to the DNS server's local `192.x.x.x` IP.*

---

Comment: First of all, HUGE thanks for the detailed answer and all other people!
Second, i'll add some more details and explain more about the situation.
`gal@hostmaster:/etc$ host nas.techvision.me
nas.techvision.me has address 192.168.1.100
gal@hostmaster:/etc$ host 192.168.1.100
100.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer nas.techvision.me.`
this resolving correctly from the server itself,
the server is standard debian 10 latest version running on ESXi VMware.
and from another PC on LAN :
`Ping request could not find host router.techvision.me. Please check the name and try again.`

Comment: @darth_static
`managed-keys.bind.jnl: open: permission denied`
`May 25 05:00:52 hostmaster named[10429]: client @0x7fd3846dce30 169.254.94.66#58829 (time.windows.com): query (cache) 'time.windows.com/AAAA/IN' denied`
dns is not forward through router, I only have local use at the moment for those hostnames resolves.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can do to test the overall setup:

- Restart Bind9 and check the log file for any errors on startup. If it's not in its own logfile it'll be in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/messages`. Look out for "zone not loaded due to errors", check the preceding lines, and fix any issues.
- Your configs don't contain any `rndc` TSIG keys. I'm hoping that's because you intentionally removed them before posting, otherwise this won't work. Run `rndc querylog on` and monitor the logfile. You should see an entry saying `query logging on`. Run a dig or nslookup command from the Windows host and check the log on the server. If DNS lookups are working properly from the server, this step is most likely to reveal the issue.
- Install `tcpdump` on the server and invoke it using this command before performing some lookups from the Windows machine: `tcpdump -nnvvv "udp port 53"`. You should see a line starting like the following: `[timestamp] IP [Windows IP]:[random high port] > 192.168.1.254:53 [...]` This indicates that the DNS request is getting to the server. If there is no response packet (i.e. one where the Windows IP and the server IP are switched) then the server is not listening on the right ports, or the packet is blocked. If there isn't a packet from the Windows machine, the network isn't configured correctly.

Comment: nslookup from windows host responding : Default server : UnKnown

tcpdump shows good communication.

Maybe something with the endc TSIG keys,
`name: techvision.me
type: master
files: /etc/bind/db.techvision.me
serial: 40
nodes: 5
last loaded: Wed, 19 May 2021 09:04:57 GMT
secure: no
dynamic: yes
frozen: no
reconfigurable via modzone: no`
I am seen alot of interesting stuff in the log file, how could i paste them here.

Comment: I think the best way is to put it on Pastebin, after redacting IPs and sensitive information of course.

Comment: Okay, looking at your other comment there's a problem to be fixed, but I doubt it's the cause. Move the file `managed-keys.bind.jnl` out of the directory where it's in; it's most likely useless but it's not worth immediately deleting it. 

The denied query to time.windows.com isn't an issue as you're not listening on IPv6.

Is there anything in the output of `iptables -t nat -vnL` that could explain the issue? NAT on internal networks usually breaks things.

Comment: Actually i'm strong with the network things,
I'm sure nothing breaks there. router giving one dhcp lease with 1segment, 192.168.1.x,
dns configured manually to navigate client 192.168.1.254 which is the bindserver.
bind server configuration seems to be correct.
Maybe some cache history on windows for faster resolving or somerthing ?
Because I do own this domain with cloudflare management and had cloudflare dns configured before..
Or maybe IPv6 configurations messing things.

Answer (score 0):

Well, problem solved.
Windows has DNSCacheHistory that caused respond to navigate automatically from history.

This is the following command to ***Flush Windows DNS Cache History :***

> ipconfig/flushdns

And in addition, make sure IPv6 is not set as default somewhere or else make sure to configure AAAA rDNS file.

Thanks everyone for the help, this community is the best!